# Dependency react-native-svg is not working in android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, svg

I have added react-native-svg using command "npm install react-native-svg --save"
But when I run my app using command "react-native run-android" it is showing following error.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/gireesh/Desktop/TCSOccasions/old/TCSOccasions/android/app/build.gradle' line: 140
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Project with path ':react-native-svg' could not be found in project ':app'.

Here is my package.json file dependencies.

"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.0",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2"
  },

I am using "react-native-svg" for "react-native-qrcode-svg" to generate qrcode from a string. It is working fine in IOS the problem occurs only with android. Can some one please help me??

Answer (score 0):

You also have to link the dependency using `react-native link react-native-svg` 
or manually adding the native dependency inside of `gradle config files` and `java` code.

it is on the readme [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#notice)